# How to add data in bidirectional manytomany mapping?(ITS NOT A NORMAL PROCESS OF ADDING DATA)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm

```
public class Movies {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int movie_id;

        @Column(unique = true, length = 255)
        private String movie_name;

        private String movie_language;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<Actors> actors;

        private String movie_genre;
           //Getter-Setters
    }

    public class Actors {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int actor_id;

        private String actor_name;

        private String actor_industry;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "actors")
        Set<Movies> movies;

            //Getter-Setters
        }

    /*This is where my logic resides*/
```

I have two entity Movies and Actors which has ManyToMany mapping.
        If I add a movie with Actors,I am able to see that in databse with additional table which maps Movies and Actors.

Now suppose If I'm entering another new movie with same actor,It gives me an error that Actor already exist(Here actor_name in Actors and movie_name in Movies is unique),

How to add a movie in db such that It should enter new movie in Movies table but If actor already exist in Actors table It should simply map new Movie with already existing actor.

For example:First enter this

```
{
  "movie_name":"Titanic",
  "movie_language":"English",
  "release_year":"1997",
  "movie_genre":"Romance",
  "actors":[
    {
      "actor_name":"Leonardo",
      "actor_industry":"Hollywood"  
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to enter second movie as:

```
{
  "movie_name":"Once upon a time in hollywood",
  "movie_language":"English",
  "release_year":"2019",
  "movie_genre":"Drama",
  "actors":[
    {
      "actor_name":"Lenardo",
      "actor_industry":"Hollywood"  
    },
    {
      "actor_name":"Brad",
      "actor_industry":"Hollywood"  
    }
  ]
}
```

:::::This is How I add new movie:::::::

```
public void addMovie(Movies movie) {
        Movies tempMovie = movieRepository.findByName(movie.getMovie_name());
        if (tempMovie != null) {
            Set<Actors> actors = new HashSet<Actors>();
            actors = movie.getActors();
            for (Actors actors2 : actors) {
                tempMovie.getActors().add(actors2);
            }
            movie = tempMovie;
            movieRepository.save(movie);
        } else {
            System.out.println("############################In else");
            Set<Actors> actors = movie.getActors();
            for (Actors actors2 : actors) {
                System.out.println(actors2.getActor_name());
                Actors actorTemp = actorRepository.findByName(actors2.getActor_name());
                // System.out.println("Id::::"+actorTemp.getActor_id());
                if (actorTemp != null) {
                    System.out.println("Actor is there " + actors2.getActor_name());
                    System.out.println("Before" + actorTemp.getMovies());
                    actorTemp.getMovies().add(movie);
                    System.out.println("After:" + actorTemp.getMovies());
                    movie.getActors().add(actorTemp);
                    System.out.println("Added");
                    movieRepository.save(movie); //If I remove this line,then there's no error,but also no changes in DB.....without this line my new movie won't be persisted.
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Actor is new");
                    movieRepository.save(movie);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please share some code of your repository (/-ies), how do you persist/update your entities

Comment: I have added logic,Please check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like a bridge-table or join-table containg the identifiers for the movies and actors. This [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) explains pretty good what you need to implement for this szenario. In order to avoid errors because of duplicate records in your DB get familiar with the difference between JPA's merge vs. persist (I'm assuming that you're using JPA due to the annotations).
I hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: Hi rotzaug,
Actually I have implemented my code but problem comes when I want to add new movie containing already existing actor in DB.
I'm using JpaRepository.
I'm fetching actors data that I want to add(If its already in DB) and then attaching new movie entity using "actor.getMovies().add(newMovie)".
Its working fine until now,but if I'm saving movie again then Its throwing error that actor is already there.

Comment: Hi! how exactly are you saving the movie? can you provideo some code of that process?

Comment: Unable to provide entire block as its exceeding length,but I'm checking if movie is already there or not.
If movie is not there then I'm using 
                movieRepository.save(movie);
else I'm checking if new movie has any existing actors or not.
      If actor is there then fetching movies associated with that actor and adding new movie at the end of set.

Comment: Are you updating the actor entity after adding the movie and saving it? I mean the actor entity in the `Set<Actor>` ? Try reassign the actor in the set (which is hard to do on a set and also why you usually use a `List` for this). Since you have `CascadeType.ALL` , why are you saving your movie at all?

Comment: Movie is my primary entity,So I'm saving movie including actors as a set.

Comment: in `for (Actors actors2 : actors) { tempMovie.getActors().add(actors2); }` you are adding the actors and you assume, that the actors which are already in the Set won't be added. But is that really the case? Debug this and check if the `tempMovie.actors` is correct after that for-loop. Check your `equals()` method for `Actors`. Check how your `Actors` entities look like that come from the tempmovie in the database and how the `Actors` look like that come from the `movie`. You just have to debug alot and you will find out why it's not working.